# Google SignIn - Error signing in the specified account

Tags: android, google-plus

I made an application that uses user's gmail account to connect. The problem is that it worked perfectly when running on device but after getting the release apk and installing it on my phone it only works the first time. If I open it again I get

```
"Error signing in the specified account. please choose a different account."
```

I paid attention when registering it to the GoogleApiConsole. The name of the package I registered it with is the same as the one in manifest, gradle, etc so this is not the problem.

I know that there are already a lot of questions dealing with this but none of the solutions provided helped me so far. 
Any tips/ideas what might be wrong?

My login class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    // Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // Profile pic image size in pixels
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
    public static String username;
    public static String user_email;
    public static String user_pic;
    public static Person.Cover.CoverPhoto user_cover;



    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
     * from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic, logo;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        setContentView(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.layout.activity_main);


        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.btn_sign_out);
        btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.btn_revoke_access);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.imgProfilePic);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.txtEmail);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.llProfile);
        logo = (ImageView) findViewById(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.poind2);

        // Button click listeners
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);


            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

        }
        else
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoInternetConnection.class));
        }
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to resolve any signin errors
     * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                // resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();

        // Update the UI after signin
        updateUI(true);

    }

    /**
     * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
     * */
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {


        if (isSignedIn) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, myprofile.class));
            /*/
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            /*/
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                //Person.Cover.CoverPhoto cover = currentPerson.getCover().getCoverPhoto();

                username = personName;
                user_email = email;
               // user_cover = cover;
                user_pic = personPhotoUrl;

                //add user to the USERS DATABASE
                add_user(personName,email);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(imp.poinder.diana.track.R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Button on click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.btn_sign_in:
                // Signin button clicked
                signInWithGplus();
                break;
            case imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.btn_sign_out:
                // Signout button clicked
                signOutFromGplus();
                break;
            case imp.poinder.diana.track.R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                // Revoke access button clicked
                revokeGplusAccess();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-out from google
     * */
    public void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
            logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Toast.makeText(this, "User is disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Revoking access from google
     * */
    private void revokeGplusAccess() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                            updateUI(false);
                        }

                    });
            logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
     * */
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

    // ADD USER TO THE DATABASE
    void add_user(String txtName, String txtEmail)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        InputStream is = null;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", txtName));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", txtEmail));

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http:/xxxxx/users_in.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            String msg = "Data has been sent successfully";
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_Tag");
            e.printStackTrace();
            String msg2 = "Log_Tag";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Log_Tag", "No Internet Connection!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            String msg3 = "IOException";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any logcat error? Put your login class please

Comment: You are using OAUTH 2.0 protocol for handling authentication yes/

Comment: @Diana did you created client id using the release apk?

Comment: @KaranMer I didn't know I had to make a different client id for a release apk I just used the one from my debug apk. I have created now a client id for my release apk and it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create client Id for your app from google developer console in order to use google login with your signed apk. So, create client id using the credentials (package name and sha) and your app will work fine.